# Exclude column from sorting in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a simple Swing JTable and a TableRowSorter made by me. However, I would exclude the first column from the sorting, as I want to keep it to show row numbers.
I can't see to find anything, except

```
sorter.setSortable(0, false);
```

Which makes the column not clickable, but still sortable when another column is clicked...
So quick question will be: how to keep a column from being sorter by a TableRowSorter?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, with a JTable (ex below) sorting on column A would produce the following. However, you want the data to sort, but not the row numbers, correct?

```
|row| column A  |       |row| column A  |
+---+-----------+       +---+-----------+
| 1 | blah blah |  -->  | 1 | blah blah |
| 2 | something |       | 3 | more blah |
| 3 | more blah |       | 2 | something |
```

I would approach this with a [TableCellRenderer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) for column 0. The trick is to ignore the value passed and instead use the row parameter.

```
public class RowRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object color,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        setText(Integer.toString(row));
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Note:** if you are paginating your table (ie the model does not contain all of the rows; for example only rows 100-200) you will need to advise the cell renderer of the amount to add to `row` to obtain the row number to display.

Comment: Excellent :-) I got this already working from the previous suggestion, but yours is definitely the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

A JTable is designed around displaying rows of data, not cells of data, so it isn't really possible to prevent an individual column from sorting, as you put it.  Instead I would try modifying your `TableModel` to return the row index for the value for that column:

```
@Override public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) return rowIndex;
    else {
        // handle other columns
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work you could also try modifying the table cell renderer to use the table row index instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :-) I've already implemented the getValueAt() as you said, but the column remains sortable when other columns are clicked. I will try with the table cell renderer.

Comment: Second idea worked, thanks. Just do a setCellRenderer on the TableColumn you don't want to sort, and create a TableCellRenderer where the value is value = rowIndex+1;

Comment: I noticed as well that the first method didn't work, shortly after posting.  I think it's still possible, but it's definitely the more complicated solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the row number isn't part of the data, then it should not be stored in the model.

Instead I would use a row header that displays a row number. Something like you would see in Excel. You can use the [Row Number Table](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/) for this.