# How to sort only specified columns in JTable?

Tags: java, sorting, jtable

I have a table with columns **| Name | Start | Finish | Time | Place | Points |** and I want to keep Place and Points isolated when sorting table by Time. Is there any way to do that without creating two tables?

Comment: What do you mean by 'isolated'? They should not be sorted?

Comment: @Manu Yes, place and Points order should not alternate when sorting table.

Comment: Exclude column from sorting in JTable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900234/exclude-column-from-sorting-in-jtable

Comment: @Manu, thank you, that was just what i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with using [TableCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) for Place and Points columns as Manu suggested by sharing [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900234/exclude-column-from-sorting-in-jtable).

Firstly, I created CustomTableCellRenderer and used this method to set values:

```
public class CustomCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{

    ...

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if(column==this.columnPlace){
            // set Place
         setText(Integer.toString(row+1));
        }
        else{
         // set Points depending on competitorsCount and row
            setText(Integer.toString(points[competitorsCount-1][row]));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then I set this custom renderer for these columns:

```
    CustomCellRenderer customRenderer = new CustomCellRenderer(competitorsCount);
    customRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    tableColumnModel.getColumn(columnPlace).setCellRenderer(customRenderer);
    tableColumnModel.getColumn(columnPoints).setCellRenderer(customRenderer);
```